# How to embed greek text in the pdf using Textstudio

Tags: greek, embedding

I have generated a pdf that includes some greek text.

When I open the **compiled** pdf and I **copy** the greek sentence and then **past** it somewhere e.g. in a txt file, I get weird results.

*Example:*

I get: **H arq thc sofÐac eÐnai h anaz thsh.**

Instead of: **H αρχή της σοφίας είναι η αναζήτηση**

**How can I embed the greek text to the pdf?**

For my tex documnt I use:

```
\begin{raggedleft}
        \foreignlanguage{greek}{H αρχή της σοφίας είναι η αναζήτηση}. \\
     ---  \foreignlanguage{greek}{Σωκράτης}\\
\end{raggedleft}
```

Comment: It will be useful to know which TeX engine you're using and how you've set up your document (e.g., document class, packages and fonts used)

Comment: I use a template (https://github.com/glederrey/EPFL_thesis_template/blob/master/head/settings_epfl_template.tex) and I start with \begin{document}

Comment: Everything works fine for me. The only thing which comes to my mind is that you are pasting the string copied from the pdf into an editor which isn't using `utf8` as encoding, but it's only a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

texstudio is just the editor you used to write the file so is not involved, other than to make sure you save in UTF-8.

You did not provide any example or show if you got an error in the log file so hard to give specific help other than say that this produces the expected result:

From xelatex or lualatex cut and paste should work by default but for pdftex you need to enable the glyph to unicode mapping with the two lines as below, until the next release when they will be enabled already in the latex format.

[image]

If I cut and paste from xpdf to here I get

```
Some text.
Η αρχή της σοφίας είναι η αναζήτηση.
— Σωκράτης
```

Source file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{raggedleft}
        \foreignlanguage{greek}{H αρχή της σοφίας είναι η αναζήτηση}. \\
     ---  \foreignlanguage{greek}{Σωκράτης}\\
\end{raggedleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Texstudio default encoding is UTF-8. I still get weird output when I copy and paste the sentence in a txt or word file. if you copy the sentence "H αρχή της σοφίας είναι η αναζήτηση" from the PDF, does it work for you? I use this template here:https://github.com/glederrey/EPFL_thesis_template

Comment: thanks for the reply. where should I put that? also, I have modified my initial post stating that: "When I open the compiled pdf and I copy the greek sentence and then past it somewhere e.g. in a txt file, I get weird results."

Comment: Thank you. The second suggestion did not work however it seems that adding \usepackage{cmap} solved my problem and now my pdf is copy-pastable !!!

Comment: @seralouk cmap is a slightly different method, try the version in the answer now, the added lines will be done by default in texlive 2021

Comment: Amazing. It worked perfectly. Thank you. Just for the record, what is the difference with camp?

Comment: @seralouk it uses a different method internally in the PDF to mark what needs marking, I forget the details to be honest:-)

Comment: For me it works out of the box with `pdftex` on TeXlive 2017 without `glyphtounicode` (but of course with explicit `inputenc`). Any idea why?

Comment: Yes. Only `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and of course `babel`. Then I can give greek text both directly or with the babel syntax (`>'a` and so on). In both cases I can copy the pdf output and paste it into a text file without problems.

Comment: @campa oh sorry same here, maybe the fonts/babel have the cmap data set up already, can't check now. (If anyone who knows anything wants to edit the above answer or post a more correct one then feel free)